# Caching in Imageflow Server

Tags: imageflow

I am using the following docker compose configuration to start the imageflow server:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:

  imageflow:
    image: imazen/imageflow_server_unsecured:latest
    volumes:
      - "imageflow_data:/home/imageflow/data"
      - "./data/nginx-www/sup-images:/home/imageflow/data/sup-images"
    networks:
      - network-core
      - sup
    restart: always
    entrypoint: '/bin/sh -c "sudo chown -R imageflow /home/imageflow/ && /home/imageflow/imageflow_server start --bind-address 0.0.0.0 --data-dir /home/imageflow/data/ --mount /data/sup-images/:ir4_local:/home/imageflow/data/sup-images/"'

volumes:
  imageflow_data:
    driver: local
```

I would like to understand how the cache is working, if there is one per default. I am a bit worried that I might exceed disk space or memory on a production server. Could someone please let me know how it works or point me to the documentation somewhere? Unfortunately I could not find any concerning this topic.

Answer (score 0):

imageflow_server_unsecured is discontinued and should not be used.

You should use Imageflow Server instead - there are example Dockerfiles in the repository. https://github.com/imazen/imageflow-dotnet-server

Imageflow Server implements disk caching with a write-ahead-log, so that disk utilization can be accurately limited.